# How to import custom QML element using qmldir and QML module

Tags: qt, qml

If I use `import MyModule 1.0` I got an error message what MyModule is not installed.

```
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/main.qml:3:1: module "MyModule" is not installed
```

But I correctly wrote qmldir file and resources file.
And if I use `import "MyModule"` all is Ok. But I need to use import without quotes and import my modules in all files in different dirrectories. How to correctly import custom Qml element?

File structure

```
QMLDIRTEST
│   CMakeLists.txt
│   main.cpp
│   main.qml
│   qml.qrc
│
└───MyModule
        qmldir
        RedRectangle.qml
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(QmlDirTest VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(QT NAMES Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Quick REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} COMPONENTS Core Quick REQUIRED)

set(PROJECT_SOURCES main.cpp qml.qrc)
add_executable(QmlDirTest ${PROJECT_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(QmlDirTest PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Core Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Quick)
```

qml.qrc

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>main.qml</file>
        <file>MyModule/RedRectangle.qml</file>
        <file>MyModule/qmldir</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if QT_VERSION < QT_VERSION_CHECK(6, 0, 0)
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
#endif

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.addImportPath("qrc:/Ui");
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import MyModule 1.0
//import "MyModule"

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    RedRectangle { anchors.centerIn: parent }
}
```

RedRectangle.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.15

Rectangle {
    width: 200
    height: 100
    color: "red"
}
```

qmldir

```
Module MyModule

RedRectangle 1.0 RedRectangle.qml
```

Comment: Try adding `engine.addImportPath("qrc:/");`.

Comment: In qmldir `module` keyword must be lowercase

Comment: @Mike I changed, but it does not helped me

Comment: @smr Your comment is correct. Please write as answer. And can you explain why this works? Can I realized it in CMake file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, `addImportPath` is needed to tell the engine where to search for the new modules that you have provided.

[QQmlEngine::addImportPath](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qqmlengine.html#addImportPath) states:

> Adds a path as a directory where the engine searches for installed modules in a URL-based directory structure. The path may be a local filesystem directory, a Qt Resource path (`:/imports`), a Qt Resource URL (`qrc:/imports`), or a URL.

After *Qt 6.**, there is a [`qt_add_qml_module`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt-add-qml-module.html) function in CMake that you can use to add new modules using only CMake. This function will automatically generate the `qmldir` and *resource files*.

```
qt_add_qml_module(${PROJECT_NAME}
    URI module.uri
    QML_FILES Component1.qml Component2.qml
)
```

In *Qt 6.**, there is a `qrc:/qt/qml` in the default import path list. By using `qt_policy(SET QTP0001 NEW)` in your CMake file, the generated resources (using `qt_add_qml_module`) will have `/qt/qml` as their default prefix. This allows the engine to detect your module without needing to add any new import paths. (ref: [QTP0001](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt-cmake-policy-qtp0001.html))

You can check this by printing `engine.importPathList()`, and you will see `qrc:/qt/qml` in the output list.

```cpp
qDebug << engine.importPathList();
// Output:
// ("path/to/build-directory/", "path/to/Qt/6.6.1/current-kit/qml", "qrc:/qt-project.org/imports", "qrc:/qt/qml")
```

#### The Qt 5.* solution

You can use the same trick in Qt 5 as well.
By printing `importPathList`, you will see that there is `/qt-project.org/imports` as the default resource path in the import path list:

```cpp
qDebug << engine.importPathList();
// Output: 
QList(
    "path/to/build-directory/",
    "path/to/Qt/5.15.2/current-kit/qml",
    "qrc:/qt-project.org/imports",
)
```

So, by adding `/qt-project.org/imports` to your resource prefix, you can make the engine recognize your provided module. For example:

**qml.qrc**

```xml
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>main.qml</file>
    </qresource>
    <qresource prefix="/qt-project.org/imports">
        <file>MyModule/RedRectangle.qml</file>
        <file>MyModule/qmldir</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

To ensure that the linter recognizes your modules, you can also set the `QML_IMPORT_PATH` variable in your CMake file.

```
list(APPEND QML_DIRS "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/.")
set(QML_IMPORT_PATH "${QML_DIRS}" CACHE STRING "Qt Creator extra qml import paths")
```